# Does Nest provide an API for my app to auto-detect/discover a new device being added

Tags: nest-api

I created an app using the API instructions at developer.nest.com website. So the app can get a list of existing devices and control them the way I want.

But what if I want the app to do something special anytime I add a new device? Is this possible today? Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can listen to updates several different ways. It depends on what you're using: Firebase, Rest Stream, Rest polling, etc. 
Basically, you'll need to create a Listener in your code, and after that check on triggered events. You can listen to different levels: structure or the whole account (root level).

If you have a Rest stream, you can check out this curl command to see what's getting triggered in JSON:

1.Open console and Nest developer tool

2. Run this at the console (root level) with the access token* you have for your client :
   curl -L -v "https://developer-api.nest.com?auth=" -H "Accept: text/event-stream”

3.Remove any thermostat from your virtual account.

4.Check the triggered events in the console: you'll have your JSON missing the data for the thermostat you just removed.

5.Now go one level up to the structures: curl -L -v "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/?auth=" -H "Accept: text/event-stream”

6. Repeat the same procedure with the virtual devices.

*To get access token for your client go here: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-auth

In case you want to check this out on a code level, you can find it in the [Nest Sample Code](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/sample-code). All of the samples have Listeners which allow you to see any changes happening to the thermostats in the account/structure.

P.S. It's better to use Firebase or Rest Stream if you want those events to be triggered real-time.